# Converting polygon geometries to polygonz geometries using GeoTools?

Tags: polygon, convert, geotools

I have a shapefile which contains a lot of polygon records. These polygon geometries contains points which has x and y coordinate pairs. I want to add z values (z=0) for every polygon points thus I can convert polygon geometry type to polygoz. But I don't know how do that using geotools. Here which I tried so far;

```
public List<Geometry> getGeometries(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<Geometry> geometriListesi = new ArrayList<Geometry>();

    File file = new File(filePath);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());

    DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
    String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

    SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = source.getFeatures();
    System.out.println(collection.size());

    SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collection.features();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
        Geometry g = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
        geometrilistesi.add (g.boundary());
     }
     return geometriListesi;
   }
```

Now I am stuck and can't decide how to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply a `CoordinateFilter` to your `Geometry` / `Polygon`:

```
for(Geometry geom : geometryList) {
    // expecting Polygon in your case...
    geom.apply(new CoordinateFilter() {

        @Override
        public void filter(Coordinate coord) {
            // this will change the Z coordinate value from NaN to 0.0!
            coord.z = 0;                    
        }

    });
}
```